# What would you see if left-right images of a 3d view are inverted?

Tags: language-agnostic, 3d, vision

Sorry for the maybe-trivial post, but I really cannot figure it out...

Let's suppose you have some 3d glasses or something that allows you a 3d stereo vision.

What happens if you invert left and right image??? Thinking at it I cannot really figure out it. Should you see the reverse of the image? Or just some axis-shift?

Unfortunately I cannot try it out in any way, but even if possible, I'd love to try to figure out and understand the *thing* with my mind before trying it.

So, please, any help, any idea, any hit that can help me to understand or to deeply discuss are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the human brain it's next to impossible to give a formal answer, because frankly, neurologists still don't fully understand how it works in detail. But so much we know:

Our brain does no absolute "measurement" on the parallax in stereo images. The whole depth perception works on parallax differences. You could say, the brain takes the derivative of the parallax to build it's mental representation of depth. Derivative of Parallax and depth are taken to be (nearly) proportional. By swapping the pictures the derivative gets negative, so at every point the brain sums up depth in the wrong direction.

However parallax is not the only source for depth perception. Of similar importance is experienced knowledge about typical object in the world. For example faces are "known" to be never inside out, so even with negative parallax the knowledge will overrule and the face being percept in the right form (however it'll clash hilariously with the surroundings).

Comment: I've not been able to test it, up to now. But your explanation satisfied me! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shadows play a very important role on depth perception, too, as the "relief" used on classic GUI widgets, and drop shadows used nowadays, have shown. Noteworthy, either, is how using "sunlight" in Google Earth enhances the depth understanding of certain landscape, for the viewer. It would be interesting to mix stereoscopic images with shadows and parallax suggesting opposite curvatures, to see which one "prevails".

Answer (score 0):

You would see it as "inside-out" (it's a little more complex than that, but that's the basic truth).

Comment: Find one of those "Magic Eye" images that required you to keep your eyes relaxed and pointing straight to view properly. Now view it by crossing your eyes. Same effect. +1

Comment: I'm quite convinced of it. But can someone give me some kind of "formal" proof of it? (I know, I'm pedantic, but I really need to understand...)

Answer (score 0):

You can experience 3D without any special hardware, thanks to stereoscopic images (side-by-side, then crossing your eyes to see the images as one unique image).

You can then switch right to left, left to right by editing the image.

Here is an example with an image I've found on the web: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlIPh.jpg

Do you feel any difference in the depth? Do you see things inside out?

I believe the sense of depth in this case is preserved. But maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 0):

In 2011 I got involved with a study in 3D video cameras. I wound up shooting some material, and working with some amazing 3D video cameras. Sometimes, when looking at the video from a camera, I would get the left eye and right eyes reversed. The resulting image on the 3D monitor initially looked like blurry 2D. Then your brain will start to try to figure out small pieces of the image, and parts of the picture will start to take on a 3D ness, but the image did look inside out. Kind of like you were inside the object looking out. If you stared at the video for 10-15 seconds, the smaller parts started to merge into larger areas that displayed this inside out 3D look. I then stopped the video, and looked at another part of the room (reality), and the room seemed to be in 2D at first. Then after 10-15 seconds the 3D perception slowly came back in my eyes. It was a very strange experience.